# Re scaling an object from its current scale to a scale of 0

Tags: unity, c#, animation, gameobject, scale

I want to have an animation which starts at a starting scale of whatever the current gameObject's scale (i.e 1, 1, 1 or 2, 3, 2) is which then end at a scale of 0, 0, 0.

The problem is that Unity's animator has fixed values and so, I cannot make one animation that would easily apply to every object.

I'm fine with using C# code to do this but I haven't been able to find anything that works yet. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Seems like you should get yourself a Tween engine. [There's a few](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/page=1/sortby=relevance/query=tween) on the asset store, a lot of them are even free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take 2 things into account:

- duration
- current scale value

Scale property is a Vector3 (x,y,z) and you want to go from initial_scale_value to Vector3.Zero. Here is an example you can use in a coroutine.

```
private IEnumerator Unscale()
{
    float ratio = 0;
    float duration = 5; // let's say we want a 2s animation
    float start_time = Time.time; // time when the animation began
    Vector3 initial_scale_value = transform.localScale;
    do
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); // wait for next frame
        ratio = (Time.time - start_time) / duration; // update the ratio value at every frame
        transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(initial_scale_value, Vector3.zero, ratio); // apply the new scale
    } while (ratio < 1);
}
```

However, even if you can do it using a few lines of code, if you need to do that kind of stuff often I recommend you to use a Tween engine, such as [DOTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/) that I strongly recommend (I used it a lot and it does awesome things with great performances).